# Issue with API OAuth callback header not formatted correctly

Tags: javascript, api, twitter, oauth

I am trying to connect to Twitters API in order to pull down my own tweets.  I'm having trouble getting the correct header for the OAuth which is required by Twitter.  Below is what I have so far, is there something I am missing or doing wrong?

Also it asks for HMAC-SHA1 which asks for two inputs a KEY and DATA.  I believe the KEY according to Twitter is combining the consumer secret and OAuth Token Secret together, but what is the DATA input?

```
import axios from 'axios'
import hmacsha1 from 'hmacsha1'


const tweet = 'http://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=SamSchaeferSays';


const consumerKey = "XXX";
let nonce = createNonce();;
const signatureMethod = "HMAC-SHA1";
const timeStamp = Date.now();
const token = "XXXX";
const hiddenToken ="XXXXX";
const sig = `${consumerKey}&${hiddenToken}`;
const signature = btoa(hmacsha1(sig, "ok"));

const DST = `OAuth oauth_consumer_key="${consumerKey}", oauth_nonce="${nonce}", oauth_signature="${signature}", oauth_signature_method="${signatureMethod}", oauth_timestamp="${timeStamp}", oauth_token="${token}", oauth_version="1.0"`;

function createNonce() {
     let randMe = "";
     let possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
         for( var i=0; i < 5; i++ )
             randMe += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));
     return btoa(randMe);
 }

function getUserTweet() {
    return axios.get(`${tweet}`, { headers: { 'Authorization': `${DST}` } }).then(function(response){
        console.log(response.data)
        console.log(response.status)
    }).catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error)
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The data is basically your request (Method and parameters) encoded in a way described on the [Twitter API site](https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/overview/creating-signatures).
Will end up something like

```
urlEncode(headers.keys().sort().map(key => `${key}=${headers[key]}`).join("&"))
```

Comment: Yes I have read the API website which is how I have made it this far.  I believe the problem is my signature - I think you have to recreate the entire DST for the signature as well.  Its a little confusing

Comment: Yes all the headers have to be in there again, alphabetically. Something like

`headers.keys().sort().map(key => key+"="+headers[key]).join("&")`

so yes your `DST` string is wrong because it has commas and spaces where it should be one long string with `&` (and then `urlEncode`)

Comment: I think the DST string is correct.  By following Twitter API rules Append the string “OAuth ” (including the space at the end) to DST.
For each key/value pair of the 7 parameters listed above:
Percent encode the key and append it to DST.
Append the equals character ‘=’ to DST.
Append a double quote ‘”’ to DST.
Percent encode the value and append it to DST.
Append a double quote ‘”’ to DST.
If there are key/value pairs remaining, append a comma ‘,’ and a space ‘ ‘ to DST.

Comment: My signature is incorrect, as you have to basically rebuild the DST as a signature and then include that with the original DST